# How customize a plot inside a R function which belong to a package?

Tags: r, plot, package, cran

I'm preparing a small r-package and I would like to use the function `plot()` on an object created through a function, and getting a customized plot. For instance, this is a very silly example function:

```
myfun <- function(x,y){

A <- B <- c()

  for(i in 1:x) {
    A[i] <- i^2
    B[i] <- i^2+1}

  return(list(A,B))
}
```

Then, I create a list with 2 vectors:

```
obj <- myfun(5,6)
```

So, the standard approach to get a plot would be:

```
plot(x=obj[[1]],y=obj[[2]], main='my title',type = 'b', col='red)
```

BUT, instead of that, I would like to run the following:

```
plot(obj)
```

And get the same. So I don't know how to code that into my function in order to get a completely personalize plot. Also, I would like to get a customized summary table, for instance, running the following:

```
summary(obj)
```

Be able to get a table with means, sd, etc.
I was looking all over StackOverflow about this, with no success, but maybe I used the wrong keywords. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You have to add an S3 method to plot...e.g. `plot.your_class <- function(your_dat){plot(x=obj[[1]],y=obj[[2]], main='my title',type = 'b', col='red)}` Importantly, you need to assign your output object a new class as well. See <http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a class and then create your own personal method.

`plot()` and `summary()` are generic functions. If you type on your console:

```
methods(plot)
methods(summary)
```

You will see a lot of methods already do exist.

While if you print `plot` on your console you will see that:

```
 plot
 #> function (x, y, ...) 
 #> UseMethod("plot")
 #> <bytecode: 0x2363df0>
 #> <environment: namespace:graphics>
```

`plot` calls a function called `UseMethod` that will look for all the methods available in the namespaces and the global environment related to `plot`.

Edit your code this way:

```
myfun <- function(x,y){

  A <- B <- c()

  for(i in 1:x) {
      A[i] <- i^2
      B[i] <- i^2+1}

  structure(class = "myclass", list(A,B))

  }
```

This way you can create your class. Your function `myfun()` will always return an object `myclass` which is a list of two numeric vectors.

Now you can create your own methods. A method should start with the same name of the generic function and be followed by a dot and the name of your class.

```
plot.myclass <- function(obj, ...){
    plot(x = obj[[1]], y = obj[[2]], main='my title', type = 'b', col = 'red', ...)
}

obj <- myfun(5,6)
plot(obj)
```

Add `...` in case you want to add more features to your plot in the future.

Same stuff for `summary`. You can to the same for `print` for example.

PS: I would strongly advice you to use a `lapply()`, `vapply()` or a `purrr::map_dbl()` instead of a `for` loop on your example.
And to go for a neat `ggplot` instead of plot.

Answer (score 2):

If you give your myfun ouput a custom class:

```
class(obj) <- 'myClass'
```

Then add a new s3 method:

```
plot.myClass <- function(obj) {
      plot(x=obj[[1]],y=obj[[2]], main='my title',type = 'b', col='red)
}
```

Now you can use:

```
plot(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by SmokeyShakers about plotting is correct, but for your other question about being able to get a table with means, sd, etc. 
You need to convert your obj to a data frame and then run summary, to be able to get all that stats.

```
summary(data.frame(x=obj[[1]],y=obj[[2]]))

       x            y     
 Min.   : 1   Min.   : 2  
 1st Qu.: 4   1st Qu.: 5  
 Median : 9   Median :10  
 Mean   :11   Mean   :12  
 3rd Qu.:16   3rd Qu.:17  
 Max.   :25   Max.   :26
```

Edit: Or to be consistent, you can do the following:

```
summary.myClass <- function(obj){summary(data.frame(x=obj[[1]],y=obj[[2]]))}
summary(obj)
```

Comment: Or likewise, make your own method: `summary.myClass`