# Avoiding code repetition with (box)plot functions

Tags: r, plot, refactoring, decorator

For generating a couple of boxplots with the same style, I make identical calls to the boxplot function like in the following minimal example:

```
boxplot(Petal.Length ~ Species, iris, ylim=c(0,10))
abline(h=8)
legend('topleft',levels(iris$Species))

boxplot(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris, ylim=c(0,10))
abline(h=8)
legend('topleft',levels(iris$Species))
```

I would like keep my code readable and maintainable by avoiding code duplication.

Therefore, I thought of using decorators as described in
[How customize a plot inside a R function which belong to a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59053771/how-customize-a-plot-inside-a-r-function-which-belong-to-a-package) or
[Writing a decorator for R functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829558/writing-a-decorator-for-r-functions) or
https://weinstockjosh.com/post/2016-06-08-decorators-in-r/
However, I could not find a way to encapsulate/wrap around the formula used as a parameter in the `(box)plot` functions, which is beautiful syntactic sugar.

Where could I find a suitable construct offered by `R` to keep my code readable and maintainable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lapply` and `reformulate`

```
lapply(c('Petal.Length', 'Sepal.Length'), \(x) {
  boxplot(reformulate(x, 'Species'), iris, ylim=c(0, 10))
  abline(h=8)
  legend('topleft', levels(iris$Species))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

## define function to create boxplot

```
create_boxplot <- function(data, x_var, y_var, ylim_val, hline_val, legend_pos) {
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x = x_var, y = y_var)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    ylim(ylim_val) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = hline_val) +
    labs(x = x_var, y = y_var, title = y_var) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
    theme(legend.position = legend_pos)
}
```

## call function for each variable

```
create_boxplot(iris, "Species", "Petal.Length", c(0, 10), 8, "topleft")
create_boxplot(iris, "Species", "Sepal.Length", c(0, 10), 8, "topleft")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an additional alternative for people facing the same problem:

```
boxplotCustom <- function (...) {
    boxplot(..., ylim=c(0,10))
    abline(h=8)
    legend('topleft',levels(list(...)[[2]]$Species))
}

boxplot(Petal.Length ~ Species, iris)
boxplot(Petal.Length ~ Species, iris)
```

I have to admit it's two lines longer than the original solution, but could for example be of advantage when re-using the solution snippet in different files.